# Finding base address of process in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pointers, memory, executable

Im working on a tool that modifies the value of memory addresses but my problem is that the programs base memory address changes every time I open it.

So how would I go about finding the base memory address of a program In VB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try and see how it work's out for you. This doesn't change for me at all it stay's the same for me...

```
   Dim handle_s As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()
   Dim bAddress As Int64 = handle_s.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt64
```

Comment: Ok maybe I should of clarified a bit more i need the base address of another program. However I did test this it does give me my base address of my actual tool im making so it kinda works i just need to tell it to do another program but im not sure how?

I have a module for editing memory that already declares the program in case that helps

http://pastebin.com/QSWCp1Le

Comment: Haha yeah I got it by ID not name but thanks a million you are a life saver

Answer (score 1):

First, get `ProcessID` and then use `Process.MainModule` property. In example, I used `ID=8684` for my PC Notepad.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Dim myProcess As Process = Process.GetProcessById(8684)
Dim MyAddress as Intptr = myProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress
```